# Exporting to excel from OPENROWSET with cell formatting

Tags: sql-server-2012, t-sql, excel, openrowset

I am trying to generate a report from SSMS to Excel, using OpenRowSet.

All is working fine, still I have to export a specific column with a barcode font.
I already have the column calculated from SSMS, and being exported to Excel. I also have installed the right font and I can easily use it in Excel.

I am using a template that I have designed and the designated column in Excel is already set to be using the needed barcode font, but when the export is done, the column is showing the barcode value, but not the barcode itself.

Any idea?

Comment: this might be helpfull http://sqlcache.blogspot.com/2013/12/data-import-and-export-to-sql-server.html

Comment: Well this is what I am doing actually, but using another provider (ACE) not (JET). The barcode is not showing, only it's value as barcode in code 128b.

Comment: Make sure that the barcode column in the Excel spreadsheet is using the proper font. When I set the font on the Excel column, I see a barcode pattern. Perhaps the data copy is reverting the cell to the 'default' font.

Comment: I will double check, but I'm pretty sure it is in the right font. Isn't there any way to force the exported column from ssms to be in the needed font through OPENROWSET?

Comment: I do not think so. OPENROWSET is just moving data, not formatting instructions. However, When I pre-define an Excel spreadsheet cell or column with a particular font, SQL query data displays in that font.

Comment: I'll take another look to the template.

Comment: I made sure that the font is correct, even the Column name in the template is in Code 128 B font. I Even made a table design in the excel sheet to make sure that OPENROWSET is respecting the layout... the result is not what i have expected, the data were not formatted in the table design, and the barcode column is not showing the barcode also.

Comment: Please note that when copied manually from the query result to the template, it is working fine...